# Guardar en sdcard las fotos de cámara o galería desde mi aplicación en android studio

Tags: android-studio

```
private final String ruta_fotos = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/augere/";
File file = new File(ruta_fotos);
Camara.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                String file = ruta_fotos + createImageFile();
                File mi_foto = new File( file );
                 uri = Uri.fromFile( mi_foto );
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error:",""+e);
            }
        }
    });
private String createImageFile() throws IOException{
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "aug_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
    return imageFileName;
}
private void showFileChooser(){
    Intent intent= new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}
public void crearImagen(String nombreImg,String Directorio){
        File file = new File(Directorio, nombreImg);
        Log.i("","" + file);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

En mi celular me guarda en almacenamiento sdcard (interno) pero en otros celular guarda en el extSdcard y la aplicación se detiene porque no tiene microsd.

Comment: "En mi celular me guarda en almacenamiento sdcard (interno) pero en otros celular guarda en el extSdcard y la aplicación se detiene porque no tiene microsd." Los 2 casos son normales dependiendo del dispositivo, el tercero tienes que validar la existencia de sdcard.

Comment: y después que yo valide si tiene o no, como hago - Si no tiene lo guarde en el sdcard interno.